# Excel other tab multiple line and column VLOOKUP SUM

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a two tabs (data) and (summary).

My data tab looks something like this (mine has more columns but this gives you an idea:

[image]

The column order repeats every 9 columns.

In my summary tab I want it split out and a SUM of the 8th of 9 column grouped by the 1st of 9 column.

Example output from the numbers above:

```
ALPHA   45
BETA    53
CHARLIE 45
```

I have tried doing a `VLOOKUP` but this just brings back a single value.

How can I do a `VLOOKUP` that sums all found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a crude solution, SUMIF should do the job.

```
=SUMIF(A1:A7,"ALPHA",H1:H7) + SUMIF(A1:A7,"ALPHA",Q1:Q7) + SUMIF(A1:A7,"ALPHA",Z1:Z7)
```

If the total number of column groups isn't known you may need something more elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use `INDEX` not `Vlookup`

and then follow the example bellow

[image]

Check [this post](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2697-excel-vlookup-and-sum.html) as well